# Downvoting without comment.Why it's allowed?

Tags: discussion, comments, down-votes, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

Recently somebody downvotes few of my questions/answers in same time.

Without comment or reason.

Why is this allowed? Imagine this: if someone want to rapidly decrease my rep., simply look at my answers/questions and can start to destroy me very easily.

I think downwoting should be allowed after leaving comment.

I'm open to any kind of objective criticism.

Also, it is polite to explain such negatives to make sure it will not repeat in future.

PS : I already read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111242/lose-reputation-when-downvoting-without-a-comment) but does not seem for me as an answer.

Comment: Is this a feature request or a discussion? If it's a feature request you'll make Yannis write "_sigh_ not this again".

Comment: Have you tried searching Meta? It has been treated [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/176533), [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55324/176533), [up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30066/require-comments-when-downvoting) (10K), [down](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22934/176533) and many others I guess.

Comment: Sigh. [Voting is different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: @Oded: In fact, I downvoted for the lack of research effort and because I do not consider this question as useful.

Comment: @Alenanno You have a broken link in your comment.

Comment: @Da_smokes: Nope. It's just a deleted question. That's what the "10k" implies...only people with 10k reputation can see it anymore.

Comment: @rkosegi Questions and their replies are not only meant for you but for the wider SO/SE audience in general. And it's always good to have a somewhat extensive list of previous discussions. Stop taking everything so personal.

Comment: @rkosegi Sorry, didn't think of that, but it's just one out of 3 I posted. It was just to post examples of previous questions with the same topic. :) There are more if you search I think.

Comment: With a nice little (10k) addition, showing that besides the discussions which should have been visible to you, there are even more deleted discussions on the same topic.

Comment: @rkosegi Technically that is every SE's lingo. You have 4K on SO, you're not a newbie! :P

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12027205/1288) is asking for a tutorial, so it's not constructive (now closed).  In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10877807/1288) you posted a one-sentence question without showing what you tried, then you edited an answer into the question *after* someone else posted an answer.

Comment: @BilltheLizard : It's time to close my SO account.Thanks.I will recommend same for all my colleagues.

Comment: **Do not remove the question just because it is closed as a duplicate**

Comment: @6747467454 You did say "I'm open to any kind of objective criticism.  Also, it is polite to explain such negatives to make sure it will not repeat in future."  I was just doing that.  I'll give you a day or two to reconsider before deleting your account.

Comment: @6747467454 as far as I understand from studying [your reputation at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1121249/6747467454?tab=reputation), you suspect that you are getting serial down-votes. With this in mind I believe your question here has been misunderstood and unfairly heavily downvoted. As a member of MSO community I apologize for that

Comment: @gnat He only had two downvotes over an hour apart before this question was posted.  Those were the only downvotes he'd received for the past month.  This is hardly a case of serial downvoting.

Comment: @BilltheLizard OP concerns are reflected in the first and the only answer - right there, in front of you. More specifically, take a look at the first comment (_"if someone want to rapidly decrease my rep..."_) and at the changes made in the revision 2 of the answer

Comment: @gnat Yes, I read the question and the answer. That doesn't change the fact that this was clearly not a case of serial downvoting, and that this question represents about the 10,000th request to require a comment with a downvote.  I don't think anyone misunderstood the question, nor was it unfair to downvote it.

Comment: @Bill Actually I just did a quick search on "downvote comment" and could not easily find a post explaining why users are not required to comment on downvotes. I've been participating in MSO long enough to know they exist, but to a user who doesn't come to meta too much, they're not that easy to find. But regardless, I think its a bad idea to be so intolerant of new MSO users just because some variation of their question has been asked many times in the past. I could understand a few downvotes, with a comment saying the downvote was for lack of research getting upvoted many times, but not 20+

Comment: @Rachel Typing the title of this question in the "Ask Question" page brings up several questions asking the same thing.  They're not hard to find at all if you pay attention.  The OP also linked to one of them in the question.  He seems well aware of the history of this request, he's just bringing it up yet again because he disagrees with it.

Comment: Can you please express uour opinion on marking question as duplicate at the following link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219750/is-it-correct-to-mark-these-two-questions-as-a-duplicate

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If it were not allowed, we would get lots of *less* downvoting.

We don't want that, as downvoting is the most effective means to say that a post is not good (for whatever reason).

As for serial voting (either up or down) - there is a system in place that detects these and rolls them back after a day or two.

See: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: Yes, but please imagine this : if someone want to rapidly decrease my rep., simply look at my answers/questions and can start to destroy me very easily.

Comment: @rkosegi - Well. That's called serial downvoting - and you know what? There is a system in place that detects these and rolls them back after a day or two. See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Comment: So what you're saying is that there is a system in place that detects these and rolls them back after a day or two?  And it's called serial downvoting?

Comment: @John - I don't quite get the point of your comment.

Comment: @Oded - So what you're saying is that you don't quite get the point of my comment?

Comment: Just trying to inject a little humor.  Sorry if it wasn't funny.

Comment: @John - Thought you might be trying to be funny.

Comment: What's wrong with less down-voting? It affects everyone, hence why nobody is in disadvantage and more people are happy. Do serial down-voters get punished? Just yesterday some idiot(s) down-voted a couple of my questions for no reason...

Comment: @Pavel - our purpose is to collect great questions and answers, not to make people happy. Downvotes are our single best signal that something is not right in a post - reducing that reduces the quality of posts across the site and will make it closer to yahoo answers/quora. We don't want that. One thing we *all* learn to live with is the random downvote - though, even is such cases, perhaps take another look at your questions and see if you can improve them.

Comment: Down votes without comment are useless to advancing a questioner's understanding.

Comment: @Dshiz - true. But "advancing a questioner's understanding" is not the end goal.