# How can a user with no reputation offer a bounty

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

How can a user with almost no reputation offer a +500 points bounty on a question? This is the question on stack overflow: [Kernel Mode version of FindResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398558/kernel-mode-version-of-findresource)

How much reputation will the user have, after the bounty?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The bounty was posted by a different user than the user that posted the question, as per the bounty notice below the question:

> This question has an open bounty worth +500 reputation from 6747467454 ending in 7 days.

So although the user posting the question ([Vivek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1667343/vivek)) has 11 reputation, the user posting the bounty ([6747467454](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1121249/6747467454) ) has 2768 reputation after posting a 500 rep bounty

Answer (score 5):

The reputation is taken away immediately when the bounty is offered.  The user *had* enough reputation to offer the bounties when they were created.

You can see their reputation history here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1121249/6747467454?tab=reputation

(Though it seems this user wants to be deleted, we'll oblige him/her soon as someone near an actual computer sees this)

Comment: The user has no questions, and no reputation changes, so this is not the case...

Comment: @Дамян the person offering the bounty is **a different user**

Comment: @ДамянСтанчев, as Rachel explains above, the poster of the question did not offer the bounty.

Comment: Well, bounty quit is so much better than rage quit! That user is a really sour loser, one downvote caused him to quit.

Comment: Nick, @ShaWizDowArd just for the reference, it looks like user "6747467454", ex-"rkosegi" wants to be deleted because their recent question here at Meta has been dumbvoted into oblivion - ["It's time to close my SO account..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154895/downvoting-without-comment-why-its-allowed#comment444853_154895). As far as I can tell, user suspected serial downvote fraud, but their report has been spelled in a way that triggered heavily negative reaction

Comment: I don't blame him for wanting to quit.... he gets a bunch of downvotes on some old posts all at once, then when he asks on meta why people can downvote without commenting he gets far more downvotes then he's probably ever gotten before, and a bunch of snarky comments that get upvoted. I'm sure if he comes across this post and sees himself referred to as "a really sour loser", that will just make him even happier that he left. I know the meta crowd is different than the main site, however MSO represents SE as a whole and I'm not sure if this sort of hostile attitude is good for the sites