# How do I know why I'm getting downvotes, if no one comments?

Tags: support

So I asked my first question and got instantly downvoted for no reason that I can determine. How can I figure out why my question is getting downvotes so that I can fix it?

I provided code examples. I did searches to try and find the answer prior to asking. I don't get it.

---

Clarification:  If the user does searches and provides code and asks a pointed question but then gets downvotes with no comments and only some vague text in a tooltip about it being somehow unclear, but not specifically how, ...is the implication that psychic powers are the usual expectation on StackOverflow? ;-)

I guess I can adapt somewhat by pasting in 30 or 40 google searches. Then, at least, I have proof of research.

Comment: Where did you provide code examples? If they are provided by your link, please don't do that. Show the code you have tried in the question itself. Show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: OK. That is probably it. Wow, though. So tedious. It's a common example too.

Comment: Not only which search terms you used and which results you examined but also how they can not be applied in your context is excactly what we mean when we say: show your research. We don't have psychic powers that can read your mind.

Comment: ...so the question is considered useless by 4 downvotes and I can't delete it because it's too valuable according to the UI???

Comment: Account deleted instead.

Comment: You wanted to know why you got downvotes, and people here were kind enough to explain and point you to helping pages. This was a genuine attempt to make your experience better. So, should you reconsider, we will still be here to help you, ok?

Comment: @user401237 You received 1 downvote on your 1st question. I can understand that is discouraging, can you understand that maybe you missed something, or maybe the other person missed something - now you want to delete your account. --- Wait and see if someone offers an answer about why you were downvoted, answers your question, or even offers an upvote. Upvotes earn you +10, normally downvotes cost -2, but in your case you can't have less than 1; so even with a few downvotes and just 1 upvote you'll be ahead. It has been suggested that this question is a dupe, you might want to check that out.

Answer (score 5):

> for no reason that I can determine

The good news are you **actually can**

[image]

There's a whole [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help) for each Stack Exchange site, that specifies the policies for **useful questions** at these sites.

That's clearly expressed with the tooltip text appearing if you hover the downvote button.

Also see these discussions/feature requests please

- [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)
- [Downvoting without comment.Why it's allowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154895/downvoting-without-comment-why-its-allowed)

Comment: I don't see a tooltip... could my adblocker or some such plugin be at fault? Wait and let me verify that. I looked before but I had better look again.

Comment: @user401237 here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGNR2.png also worth mentioning that each meta site has a [tag:faq] tag with useful guidance as well.

Comment: @user401237 I always see a tooltip  over my mouse cursor over that button.

Comment: OK I wacked an extension and now I see it but what it means is still unclear. "This question doesn't show any..." Any? I suppose now I have to paste them all in?? How else do I show proof of my web searches? " research effort; it is unclear or not useful" What, specifically, is unclear?  The code was provided and the question was quite clear.

Comment: Maybe it was clear the question wasn't useful for future visitors. For example because it was a duplicate or because it was a very localized question where no one else would benefit from

Comment: @user401237 if it is about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55443767/578411), then it is missing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to include an working example in the question including the workaround and then describe what the issue is you want to fix.

Comment: Wow! How do you guys get time to memorize and follow all these rules?? Don't you have day jobs??

Comment: @user401237 _"Don't you have day jobs??"_  It's probably because we memoize a lot of things driving at our day jobs well Don't you have day jobs??.

Comment: @user401237 yes, I have a job. I assume you mean that as a compliment?

Comment: My job requires 9-11 hour days. I don't have time for this. You apparently do. You have a much better job than I do. It's Sunday and I'm working.

Comment: It looks like I have yes, thanks.

Comment: @user401237 Well. I am doing that sideways while watching TV in my freetime.

Comment: @user401237 Regarding Stack Overflow: We visited the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ;). Yes, Stack Exchange sites have a lot of rules, but we have some useful resources that can help you getting started.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ always thought you were sideways ...

Comment: @rene The attractors are interchanging. I could also have been saying that I watch TV sideways, when doing actions at SO ;-)